# Give my javascript array access to includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord

**Before everything, I have been making a word filter program for my discord.js bot so excuse me for the bad words!**

Since you can't add extra parameters in includes() I decided to make a var line:

```
var filteredwords = ['asshole', 'fuck']
```

But now I want to place these words (further more will be added) in the following code line:

```
if (message.content.includes('asshole'));
```

So instead of 'asshole' I want to place the array? How can I do that? Since I'm a beginner in JS I could not understand the other topics with a similar question. It would be fine if you explain it in noob language. :)

If useful, this is my full code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var filteredwords = ['asshole', 'fuck']

function commandIs(str, msg) {
    return msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('--' + str);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is started succesfully')
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (commandIs('trump', message)) {
        message.reply('He is the president of the United States of America!');
    }
    if (commandIs('putin', message)) {
        message.reply('He is the president of Russia!');
    }
    if (commandIs('spacetaco', message)) {
        message.reply('He is the first user who joined Arcanews!');
    }
    if (message.content.includes('asshole')); {
        message.reply('Do not swear please');
        message.delete();
        var colors = require('colors/safe');
        console.log(colors.red(`The following message got deleted: 
${message.content}`));
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(filterwords.some(badword=>message.content.includes(badword))){
  alert("BAD!");
}
```

Array.prototype.some iterates over the array and returns true if one of the given function called with the array elem as argument is true, therefore if it contains at least one bad word...

Comment: Why that alert? I have already a msg.reply command line. Anyways, I'll try your code :)

Comment: @M.Kaçiran I believe the alert was used to illustrate a point, not an actual suggestion for how you should implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matching here. A much faster implementation

```
var filteredwords = ['bad-word', 'another-bad-word']
var message = 'Hello this string has a bad-word in it'; // Use your messsage.content here

// In a regex - '\b' start or end of a word
// " .join('\\b|\\b') " - gives me a regex string with each of the values from filteredwords array concatinated to for a 'OR' expression
// Here is th regex exp taht is generated `\basshole\b|\bfuck\b`
if( (new RegExp( '\\b' + filteredwords.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b') ).test(message) ){
    alert('match'); // Here the word were matched
}else{
    alert('no match'); // Wooho, a safe message
}
```

Pro tip : 
RegEx solution stands out in a way that you do the match that are case-insensitive and for bad-words that appear as a part of another word eg 'dambad-Word' would give a match for bad-word

**EDIT**: Updating answer to the full-code posted by    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    var filteredwords = ['asshole', 'fuck']

```
function commandIs(str, msg) {
  return msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('--' + str);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot is started succesfully')
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (commandIs('trump', message)) {
    message.reply('He is the president of the United States of America!');
  }
  if (commandIs('putin', message)) {
    message.reply('He is the president of Russia!');
  }
  if (commandIs('spacetaco', message)) {
    message.reply('He is the first user who joined Arcanews!');
  }


  if ( (new RegExp('\\b' + filteredwords.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b')).test(message.content ) ) {
    message.reply('Do not swear please');
    message.delete();
    var colors = require('colors/safe');
    console.log(colors.red(`The following message got deleted:${message.content}`));
  }

});
```

If you want to do the matching for not whole words like say `curseWord` should be detected in the sentence `hello there youcurseword` (case insensitive as well), you can replace the last `IF` condition with :

```
// We can get rid of '\b' to make the search not limited to whole-word matching
if ((new RegExp(filteredwords.join('|'))).test(message.content))

// We can use 'i' flag to make the matching case insensitive
if ((new RegExp(filteredwords.join('|') , 'i')).test(message.content))
```

Comment: To be sure i have added the whole code, It is not only deleting. And i'm very unfamiliar with such codes you posted.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle with the snippet I've posted above and everything works as expected : https://jsfiddle.net/psad5c7v/

Comment: When I run this with the bot token it does not work: https://pastebin.com/6mP1MEXy

Comment: you'll have to be more specific here. paste in your error stack

Comment: No error at all. It just does not work. No error in consolle.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the "includes" method you used, I think the type of "message.content" is an array.

Therefore, the problem can be regard as compare two arrays. You can simply apply two loops for checking, or you can use reduce method for checking.

```
var messageA = {
  content: "Here is a asshole in it.".split(" "),
};

var messageB = {
  content: "Here is a hole in it.".split(" "),
};

var filteredwords = ['asshole', 'fuck'];

var isValidA = messageA.content.reduce(function(pre, cur) {
  if (pre) return !!filteredwords.indexOf(cur);
  return pre;
}, true);

var isValidB = messageB.content.reduce(function(pre, cur) {
  if (pre) return !!filteredwords.indexOf(cur);
  return pre;
}, true);

console.log(isValidA); // false
console.log(isValidB); // true
```